# Select values from Json to add to dropdown list

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

I am needing to select values from a JSON, that is created based off a SQL Server database, and add them to a dropdown list as value seleciotns. I am using asp.net MVC. Everything seems to be working, excpet I can not figure out how to select "value" and "name" from my Json and use them. All I need help with is selecting those varibles and using them in the code.

This is my javascript function

```
    $(function () {
        $("#ddlDepartments").change(function () {
            var selectedid = $('option:selected').val();
            var ddlSubDepartments = $("#ddlSubDepartments"); //get the dropdownlist

            if (selectedid > 0) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/RecordEntries/PopulateddlSubDepartments",
                    data: {
                        id: selectedid
                    },
                    type: "Post",
                    dataType: "Json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(data);
                        ddlSubDepartments.html("");
                        ddlSubDepartments.append($('<option></option>').val("").html("Please select a Sub Department"));
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                            ddlSubDepartments.append($('<option></option>').val(value[i]).html(name[i]));
                        }
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert('Failed to retrieve Sub Departments.');
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

And my JSON is like this, it can be edited to whatever format.

```
{"value":5,"name":"Sub Department 1"},{"value":8,"name":"Sub Department 2"}
```

EDIT: I'll add in my controller action that the jscript is calling at the beginning.

```
        public ActionResult PopulateddlSubDepartments(int id)
        {
            var query = from d in _context.SubDepartments
                        where d.DepartmentId == id
                        select "{\"value\":" + d.SubDepartmentId + "," + "\"name\":\"" + d.SubDepartmentName + "\"}";

            if (query == null)
                ViewBag.SubDepartments = false;
            else
                ViewBag.SubDepartments = true;

            return Json(query.ToList());
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to fix action

```
 public ActionResult PopulateddlSubDepartments(int id)
        {
            var query = _context.SubDepartments
                        .Where(d=> d.DepartmentId == id)
                        .Select ( i=> new {
                           Value= i.SubDepartmentId,
                           Name= i.SubDepartmentName
                           }).ToList();

            if (query == null)
                ViewBag.SubDepartments = false;
            else
                ViewBag.SubDepartments = true;

            return Json(query);
        }
```

and ajax can  be simplified too

```
 ddlSubDepartments.html("");
.....

success: function (result) {
                    
        var s = '<option value="-1">Please Select </option>';
        for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) 
       {
        s += '<option value="' + result[i].value + '">' + result[i].name + '</option>';
        }

        $('#ddlSubDepartments').html(s);
},
```

Comment: "The name d does not exist in the current context."

Comment: @Three33Steele Sorry, it is a typo, use i.SubDepartmentId  and i.SubDepartmentName

Comment: Now my alert returns [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]. Is that what it should be? It still is not populating the ddl. The answer from @mohamed BEN KHOUYA works well but is only working for records where there is only one value.

Comment: You have to use  alert(JSON.stringify(result)); And I updated my answer, pls check again.

Comment: Works like an absolute charm!! Thank you so much! This wasn't in my question because I wasn't at that point now, but I need to make one that reads two dropdowns values and selects options based off those. Should I post a whole other question for that?

Comment: @Three33Steele You are welcome! There is a rule here - one question, one answer. You better post a new question using the updated code.

Comment: could you help with my most recent question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/68626688/16505069

Comment: @Three33Steele I always will, I posted my answer , you can start with it

Answer (score 0):

value[i] doesn't exist. Try:

```
ddlSubDepartments.append($('<option></option>').val(data.value[i]).html(data.name[i]));
```

Comment: That didn't work. My dropdown did not have a value or text with that. This has been my problem. Is my Json formatted correctly? Do I need to use a parse? Maybe even a split?

Comment: Inside PopulateddlSubDepartments, var query's select...just select d and return that as json

Comment: If I just select d in my controller it returns in my alert "[object Object]". I believe I need that select statement to select both of those columns.

Answer (score 0):

you need to deserialize it to plain objet like this:

```
let obj = JSON.parse(data); // now it looks like this : {value: 5, ...}
ddlSubDepartments.append($('<option
</option>').val(obj['value']).html(obj['name']));
```

Comment: THAT WORKS! Thank you! If you have time I need my function to do two more things. I need to clear ddlSubDepartments options each time the function is ran, and also, it is only working for a Json with one set of values. Like {"value":5,"name":"SubDepartment1"},{"value":8,"name":"SubDepartment1"} doesn't work since there are two sets.

Comment: Also, would it be better for me to just change my controller where it looks like {value: 5, ...} from the start? Then I wouldn't even have to parse it?

Comment: Do you know why it is only working for selections with one data point?

Answer (score 0):

Perform the following steps

1. add class **JsonData**

```js
public class JsonData
{
    public string HtmlMsg { get; set; }
    public string HtmlBody { get; set; }
    public bool Success { get; set; }
}
```

2.add **ViewHelper** class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

public static class ViewHelper
{
    public static string RenderPartialToString(this ControllerBase controller, string partialViewName, object model)
    {
        IView view = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(controller.ControllerContext, partialViewName).View;
        return RenderViewToString(controller, view, model);
    }
    public static string RenderViewToString(this ControllerBase controller, IView view, object model)
    {
        using (var writer = new StringWriter())
        {
           controller.ViewData.Model = model;
           var viewContext = new ViewContext(controller.ControllerContext, view, controller.ViewData, controller.TempData, writer);
           view.Render(viewContext, writer);
           return writer.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

3.change **PopulateddlSubDepartments** to :

```
public ActionResult PopulateddlSubDepartments(int id)
{
  List<SubDepartment> model = (from d in _context.SubDepartments
         where d.DepartmentId == id
         select d).ToList();

   if (query == null)
      ViewBag.SubDepartments = false;
    else
      ViewBag.SubDepartments = true;

   return Json(new JsonData()
   {
        HtmlMsg = "",
        HtmlBody = this.RenderPartialToString("_DropDownList", model),
        Success = true,
   });
}
```

4.in your view change to

```
//...........................
<div class="row" id="tmpDropDownList">
      @Html.Partial("_DropDownList", Model)
 </div>
//...........................
```

5.add partialview **_DropDownList**

```
 @model List<namescpace.SubDepartment>
 @Html.DropDownList("ddlDepartments", new SelectList(Model, "SubDepartmentId", "SubDepartmentName"), "--please select--")
```

6. add script

```js
$(function() {
  $("#ddlDepartments").change(function() {
    var selectedid = $('option:selected').val();

    if (selectedid > 0) {
      $.ajax({
        url: "/RecordEntries/PopulateddlSubDepartments",
        data: {
          id: selectedid
        },
        type: "Post",
        dataType: "Json",
        success: function(result) {
          $("#tmpDropDownList").html(result.HtmlBody);
        },
        error: function() {
          alert('Failed to retrieve Sub Departments.');
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: This is a great answer and a great method for doing this. However, due to simplicity I accepted the other one. Thank you so much though!